# methods.myFunction().call() throws Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? Error

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity

I am using "web3": "1.0.0-beta.26" and is getting the following error...

*Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.*

I have rerun truffle migrate --reset and used the address generated as the TODO_LIST_ADDRESS but I am still getting the error above

Anyone encountered this before and knows how to solve it? Thanks

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      account: "test",
      taskCount: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadBlockchainData();
  }

  loadBlockchainData = async () => {
    const ethereum = window.ethereum;
    ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;
    const web3 = window.web3;
    const web3Instance = new Web3(ethereum);
    const enabledWeb3 = await ethereum.enable();
    const accounts = await web3Instance.eth.getAccounts();
    const accountAddress = await accounts[0];
    this.setState({ account: accountAddress });
    const todoList = new web3Instance.eth.Contract(
      TODO_LIST_ABI,
      TODO_LIST_ADDRESS
    );
    console.log("todoList ", todoList);

    //! ERROR 
    const taskCount = await todoList.methods.taskCount().call();
    console.log("taskCount ", taskCount);
    this.setState({ taskCount });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Hey World</h1>
        <p>Your Account: {this.state.account}</p>
        <p>Task Count: {this.state.taskCount}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**config.js**

```
export const TODO_LIST_ADDRESS = "0xb0D64f6C317448efa56A33678d718Fd715DAeddd";
export const TODO_LIST_ABI = [
  {
    inputs: [],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "constructor"
  },
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: "taskCount",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256"
      }
    ],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function"
  },
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256"
      }
    ],
    name: "tasks",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "id",
        type: "uint256"
      },
      {
        internalType: "string",
        name: "content",
        type: "string"
      },
      {
        internalType: "bool",
        name: "completed",
        type: "bool"
      }
    ],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function"
  },
  {
    constant: false,
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "string",
        name: "_content",
        type: "string"
      }
    ],
    name: "createTask",
    outputs: [],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function"
  }
];
```

Comment: Is this a truffle project? I have hit issues before where the wrong ABI was being used. Deleting the build/ folder often fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @SamiFarhat. I deleted the build/folder and tried again but can't seem to work for me. I changed my version of web3 to "web3": "1.0.0-beta.35" and is now getting following error instead! Uncaught (in promise) Error: Couldn't decode uint256 from ABI: 0x
    at SolidityTypeUInt.formatOutputUInt [as _outputFormatter]

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: I haven't toy with it for a while so can't remember how exactly i resolve it. i vaguely recall its something to do with my metamask setting which caused me not to have gas to perform the operation